# Strip all whitespace characters from a string

Tags: php, string, replace, whitespace, sanitization

I know [this comment](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php#72562) on *PHP.net*.

I would like to have a similar tool like [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) for PHP such that I can run simply

```
tr -d " " ""
```

I run unsuccessfully the function `php_strip_whitespace` by

```
$tags_trimmed = php_strip_whitespace($tags);
```

I run the regex function also unsuccessfully by

```
$tags_trimmed = preg_replace(" ", "", $tags);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get str\_replace() to strip out spaces in a PHP string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563421/cant-get-str-replace-to-strip-out-spaces-in-a-php-string)

Comment: @taztodgmail Look at the dates. This is 2009 and the other is 2013. The 2013 is duplicate of this.

Comment: FYI: the \s flag does not included utf-8 characters such as utf-8 encoded nbsp;, ps, quads and fs  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227921/simplest-way-to-get-a-complete-list-of-all-the-utf-8-whitespace-characters-in-ph

Comment: sure! I have a set of code that addresses it

Comment: Why is this popping up in the front page?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A regular expression does not account for UTF-8 characters by default. The `\s` meta-character only accounts for the original Latin set. Therefore, the following command only removes tabs, spaces, carriage returns and new lines

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/1279798/54964
$str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
```

With UTF-8 becoming mainstream this expression will more frequently fail/halt when it reaches the new UTF-8 characters, leaving white spaces behind that the `\s` cannot account for.

To deal with the new types of white spaces introduced in Unicode/UTF-8, a more extensive string is required to match and removed modern white space.

Because regular expressions by default do not recognize multi-byte characters, only a delimited meta string can be used to identify them, to prevent the byte segments from being alters in other utf-8 characters (`\x80` in the quad set could replace all `\x80` sub-bytes in smart quotes)

```
$cleanedstr = preg_replace(
    "/(\t|\n|\v|\f|\r| |\xC2\x85|\xc2\xa0|\xe1\xa0\x8e|\xe2\x80[\x80-\x8D]|\xe2\x80\xa8|\xe2\x80\xa9|\xe2\x80\xaF|\xe2\x81\x9f|\xe2\x81\xa0|\xe3\x80\x80|\xef\xbb\xbf)+/",
    "_",
    $str
);
```

This accounts for and removes tabs, newlines, vertical tabs, formfeeds, carriage returns, spaces, and additionally from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character):

> nextline, non-breaking spaces, mongolian vowel separator, [en quad, em quad, en space, em space, three-per-em space, four-per-em space, six-per-em space, figure space, punctuation space, thin space, hair space, zero width space, zero width non-joiner, zero width joiner], line separator, paragraph separator, narrow no-break space, medium mathematical space, word joiner, ideographical space, and the zero width non-breaking space.

Many of these wreak havoc in XML files when exported from automated tools or sites which foul up text searches, recognition, and can be pasted invisibly into PHP source code which causes the parser to *jump to next command* (paragraph and line separators) which causes lines of code to be skipped resulting in intermittent, unexplained errors that we have begun referring to as "textually transmitted diseases"

(It's not safe to copy and paste from the web anymore. Use a character scanner to protect your code. lol)

Comment: Like that? I tried to explain the the old one doesn't work like it should anymore

Comment: Excellent! Can you please include the count of the characters you have in your set? - - This will help us to identify that you really have a complete set of those characters. - - I accepted your answer becouse it is now more complete than the old accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, **BUT using `trim()` should be the right answer**

Comment: Shouldn't there be the `u` flag in the regex?

Comment: That is not necessary because it uses fixed strings and alternators: |  If it were done properly in a character set such as [\t\n\r\xC2\x85\xa0] then it would need a /u to signify the utf-8 string is multi-byte. (or it would strip every individual occurrence of \xC2, \x85, and \xa0 from the source text). But the character set version is not as understandable to read.

Comment: Note that you can omit the `+` sign from the regex, this would be the same: `preg_replace('/\s/', '', $str);`

Answer (score 136):

To strip *any* whitespace, you can use a regular expression

```
$str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40048457/6521) for something which can handle whitespace in UTF-8 strings.

Comment: Any other solutions. This (preg_replace) fails for me.

Comment: Kathir, with what input does it fail?

Comment: Why do people keep putting the `+` after the `s`? You don't need it for this.

Comment: It's an order of magnitude faster than replacing them one-by-one, that's why :)

Comment: This solution have 2 problems, 1st it removes all whitespace, so "public function" will become "publicfunction" which is bad, and second, it replaces whitespace even in strings, when they can be needed.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve a different problem to the OP. This is a solution for removing all whitespace from a string.

Comment: Should we expand yourcanswer with the set of whitespaces as indicated by ppostma?

Answer (score 27):

Sometimes you would need to delete consecutive white spaces. You can do it like this:

```
$str = "My   name    is";
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
```

Output:

```
My name is
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.  The pattern could be `/\s{2,}/`, but your pattern and mine would not standardize a single tab to be a single space.  Perhaps better to consume all whitespaces which occur one or more times. `/\s+/`

Answer (score 16):

```
$string = str_replace(" ", "", $string);
```

I believe preg_replace would be looking for something like `[:space:]`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function from php to trim both sides (left and right)

```
 trim($yourinputdata," ");
```

Or

```
trim($yourinputdata);
```

You can also use

```
ltrim() - Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the left side of a string
rtrim() - Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string
```

System: PHP 4,5,7

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it does natively,  exactly what is asked by the OP. It is small, clean and 'expandable' by adding extra char to be trimmed.

Comment: Trim doesn't remove spaces INSIDE the string, only on left and right. BTW, space is default in trim, you don't have to give the 2nd argument

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove all whitespaces everywhere from $tags, just use:

```
str_replace(' ', '', $tags);
```

If you want to remove new lines and such that would require a bit more...

Comment: if you don't assign the result to a variable, this would not actually do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Any possible option is to use custom file wrapper for simulating variables as files. You can achieve it by using this:

1) First of all, register your wrapper (only once in file, use it like session_start()):

```
stream_wrapper_register('var', VarWrapper);
```

2) Then define your wrapper class (it is really fast written, not completely correct, but it works):

```
class VarWrapper {
  protected $pos = 0;
  protected $content;
  public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path) {
    $varname = substr($path, 6);
    global $$varname;
    $this->content = $$varname;
    return true;
  }
  public function stream_read($count) {
    $s = substr($this->content, $this->pos, $count);
    $this->pos += $count;
    return $s;
  }
  public function stream_stat() {
    $f = fopen(__file__, 'rb');
    $a = fstat($f);
    fclose($f);
    if (isset($a[7])) $a[7] = strlen($this->content);
    return $a;
  }
}
```

3) Then use any file function with your wrapper on var:// protocol (you can use it for include, require etc. too):

```
global $__myVar;
$__myVar = 'Enter tags here';
$data = php_strip_whitespace('var://__myVar');
```

Note: Don't forget to have your variable in global scope (like global $__myVar)

Comment: This is complex, beginners might not wish to take a look at this. But for showing effort I'll upvote you so that the -1 in this post will be removed

Comment: Yes, I know it is very complex, but it works and in some cases it is really powerful. And unfortunelly it is the only way (instead of creating tempfiles, which is ugly) how to send variable to functions which works only with files (and php_strip_whitespace is not the only one). For example, you can substitute code before require - you can create own "pre-compiler" for PHP where you can do whatever you want. I use it and it becomes very powerful and useful during years of programming.

Comment: `global $$varname;` How horrible it was in 2013

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer:

`strtr($str, [' '=>'']);`

Another common way to "skin this cat" would be to use explode and implode like this:

`implode('', explode(' ', $str));`

Comment: This eliminates literal spaces, but not all **whitespace** characters (such as tabs and new lines and carriage returns).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `ereg_replace`

```
 $str = 'This Is New Method Ever';
 $newstr = ereg_replace([[:space:]])+', '',  trim($str)):
 echo $newstr
 // Result - ThisIsNewMethodEver
```

---

For the newest version, you can use

```
$tags_trimmed = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tags);
```

```
$tags_trimmed = str_replace(' ', '', $tags);
```

By using ASCII

```
$whitespaces = array(chr(32), chr(9), chr(10), chr(13));
$tags_trimmed = str_replace($whitespaces, '', $tags);

 - Space: chr(32)
 - Tab: chr(9)
 - Newline: chr(10)
 - Carriage return: chr(13)
```

Comment: ereg is deprecated since PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function. And this function is identical to its sibling [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), except for it can take a callback function which gives you more control on how you manipulate your output.

```
$str = "this is a   string";

echo preg_replace_callback(
        '/\s+/',
        function ($matches) {
            return "";
        },
        $str
      );
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please add examples in which cases the callback is useful with `preg_replace`?

Comment: Because `preg_replace()` is perfectly capable of replacing the matched string with an empty string, there is no good reason to use `preg_replace_callback()` for this asked question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$string));
```

Comment: The `trim()` call is useless -- the regex pattern will eliminate all whitespaces in the string before `trim()` gets the chance.  This unexplained snippet dump adds no new value to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this table of characters that are considered whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637343/2943403), a concise pattern can use `\pZ` and `\pC` to eliminate all of the whitespace and control characters.  Here is [a great reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to these regex metacharacters.

```
$sanitized = preg_replace('/[\pZ\pC]+/u', '', $rawText);
```

The verbose way of matching all of whitespaces in a regex pattern can look like this:

```
/
[
  \x{0009}-\x{000D}
  \x{0020}
  \x{0085}
  \x{00A0}
  \x{1680}
  \x{180E}
  \x{2000}-\x{200D}
  \x{2028}-\x{202F}
  \x{205F}
  \x{2060}
  \x{3000}
  \x{FEFF}
]+
/ux
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3g0Yk)

| whitespace characters | `/\s+/` | `/\s+/u` | `/\pZ+/u` | `/\pC+/u` | `/[\pZ\pC]+/u` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| character tabulation | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| line feed | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| line tabulation | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| form feed | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| carriage return | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| space | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| next line | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| no-break space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| ogham space mark | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| mongolian vowel separator | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| en quad | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| em quad | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| en space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| em space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| three-per-em space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| four-per-em space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| six-per-em space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| figure space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| punctuation space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| thin space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| hair space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| zero width space | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| zero width non-joiner | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| zero width joiner | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| line separator | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| paragraph separator | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| narrow no-break space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| medium mathematical space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| word joiner | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| ideographic space | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| zero width non-breaking space | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |

Answer (score -1):

It can be done like this:

```
if(!function_exists('strim')) :
function strim($str, $charlist=" ", $option=0) {
    $return = '';
    if(is_string($str))
    {
        // Translate HTML entities
        $return = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $str);
        $return = strtr($return, array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES)));
        // Choose trim option
        switch($option)
        {
            // Strip whitespace (and other characters) from the begin and end of string
            default:
            case 0:
                $return = trim($return, $charlist);
            break;
            // Strip whitespace (and other characters) from the begin of string 
            case 1:
                $return = ltrim($return, $charlist);
            break;
            // Strip whitespace (and other characters) from the end of string 
            case 2:
                $return = rtrim($return, $charlist);
            break;
                
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
endif;
```

The standard [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) functions can be a problematic when come HTML entities. That's why I wrote a "Super Trim" function what is used to handle this problem and also you can choose is trimming from the beginning, end or both sides of the string.

Comment: This is the (at best) the correct answer to a different question.  This answer does not remove the whitespace characters between non-whitespace characters.  The asked question is not focused on trimming whitespaces from the front/back of the input string.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to remove spaces from the whole string is to use the explode function and print the whole string using a for loop.

```
 $text = $_POST['string'];
            $a=explode(" ", $text);
            $count=count($a);
            for($i=0;$i<$count; $i++){

                echo $a[$i];
            }
```

Comment: It is obviously an indirect approach to generate an array of non-whitespace substrings just to implode them as a string again.  Other answers on this page offer more direct and appropriate solutions.

Answer (score -1):

The \s regex argument is not compatible with all UTF-8 multi-byte strings on every system even when paired with /u.

NOTE: This method I came up with years ago after attempting all other methods posted here at the time and finding they did not work on the platform used at my job back then with the data set that was provided to me. If someone else finds themselves in a situation where the common answers don't apply, perhaps maybe this one might help.

This PHP regular expression is one I wrote to solve this using [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) based arguments as a replacement for UTF-8 strings:

```
function remove_utf8_whitespace($string) {
   return preg_replace('/\h+/u','',preg_replace('/\R+/u','',$string));
}
```

**- Example Usage -**

**Before:**

```
$string = " this is a test \n and another test\n\r\t ok! \n";

echo $string;
```

Result:

```
 this is a test
 and another test
         ok!
```

And:

```
echo strlen($string); // result: 43
```

**After:**

```
$string = remove_utf8_whitespace($string);

echo $string;
```

Result:

```
thisisatestandanothertestok!
```

And:

```
echo strlen($string); // result: 28
```

**PCRE Argument Listing**

Source: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

```
Character  Legend                     Example    Sample Match
\t         Tab                        T\t\w{2}   T     ab
\r         Carriage return character  See below
\n         Line feed character        See below
\r\n       Line separator on Windows  AB\r\nCD   AB    CD

\N    Perl, PCRE (C, PHP, R…): one character that is not a line break    \N+    ABC
\h    Perl, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Java: one horizontal whitespace character: tab or Unicode space separator
\H    One character that is not a horizontal whitespace
\v    .NET, JavaScript, Python, Ruby: vertical tab
\v    Perl, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Java: one vertical whitespace character: line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, paragraph or line separator
\V    Perl, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Java: any character that is not a vertical whitespace
\R    Perl, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Java: one line break (carriage return + line feed pair, and all the characters matched by \v)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some special types of whitespace in the form of tags.
You need to use

`$str=strip_tags($str);`

to remove redundant tags, error tags, to get to a normal string first.

And use

`$str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);`

It's work for me.

Comment: The asked question doesn't make any indication that HTML tags are to be specially handled. The advice to use `/\s+/` has been provided in earlier answers.