# How do I strip all spaces out of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, spaces

How can I **strip** / **remove** all **spaces** of a **string** in PHP?

I have a **string** like `$string = "this is my string";`

The output should be  `"thisismystring"`

How can I do that?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279774/to-strip-whitespaces-inside-a-variable-in-php

Comment: Technically, this is a slightly different question to the duplicate question. Sometimes you might want to strips spaces without tabs.

Comment: Here is the shortest way of doing this, in case you ever need to win at Code Golf: `strtr($string,[' '=>'']);`

Comment: To only strip from the beginning and end, use the `trim` functions: https://php.net/trim

Comment: The answers that said `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string)` are wrong or rather incomplete. The correct and complete answer is: `preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $string)`. Because other solutions &nbsp; (or Alt + 255) cannot be removed from the string, but my solution even &nbsp; also deletes.

Comment: Str::remove([ '', ' '], $string);

Answer (score 1735, accepted):

Do you just mean spaces or all whitespace?

For just spaces, use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For all whitespace (including tabs and line ends), use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

(From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279774/to-strip-whitespaces-inside-a-variable-in-php)).

Comment: 1st, you don't need the `+`. `$string = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $string);` should work fine. The only thing this doesn't work on for me is non-breaking spaces. I had to use this: `$string = preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~','',$string);` to remove them. Thanks to this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12838189/631764

Comment: Newbie question out of interest: What is the difference between `space` and `whitespace`? Isn't it the same?

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV space is the regular space character between words, whitespace is any kind of space in text: regular space, new line, tab, etc

Comment: You need @ButtleButkus's answer for cleaning up WYSIWYG content, which includes non-breaking spaces.

Comment: If you're seeing strange new characters after implementing this solution, you may want to use the solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1176904/80857

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove `&nbsp;` characters

Comment: `&nbsp;` is HTML string, you need to remove it on your own.   The "whitespace" characters are HT (9), LF (10), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32). However, if locale-specific matching is happening, characters with code points in the range 128-255 may also be considered as whitespace characters, for instance, NBSP (A0).

Comment: The trim should do the right and left trim of spaces. Most of the time you want remove more than one space. Therefore it is better use a combination of trim and regex. Ex: $txt = '  Hello   World!  '; 
$txt = trim(preg_replace('/\s{2}+/','',$txt));
echo '<br>'.$txt.'<br>'; I am really surprised, that this being a common occurrence PHP API is not providing an solution for it.

Comment: I always recommend `\s+` when it is possible that multiple spaces could occur.  This way longer and fewer matches are made with fewer total replacement -- eventuating in the same result.

Comment: @ButtleButkus  The **+** is required to handle multiple spaces.  For instance 3 spaces in a row !!!!

Answer (score 70):

If you want to remove all whitespace:

`$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);`

See the 5th example on [the preg_replace documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).  (Note I originally copied that here.)

Edit: commenters pointed out, and are correct, that `str_replace` is better than `preg_replace` if you really just want to remove the space character.  The reason to use `preg_replace` would be to remove all whitespace (including tabs, etc.).

Comment: »If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function [`str_replace`] instead of `ereg_replace()`  or `preg_replace()`.«

Comment: I would not suggest using regular expressions for simple space removal. str_replace for just spaces, preg_replace for all whitespace.

Comment: @Johannes & MasterPeter:  Agreed, but the OP left a comment on another answer that he wants to strip white space.

Comment: Good point, Johannes.  I went for preg_replace() because I misread the question, and thought what he meant was whitespace generally (not necessarily the specific space character).

Comment: Hopelessly broken this one, will remove 2 or more whitespaces, not single, as requested in the example.

Comment: No, it removes one or more (plus sign means "or more", not "and more").

Comment: Worked well for me.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109339/450127)

Answer (score 52):

If you know the white space is only due to spaces, you can use:

```
$string = str_replace(' ','',$string);
```

But if it could be due to space, tab...you can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$string);
```

Answer (score 18):

[str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will do the trick thusly

```
$new_str = str_replace(' ', '', $old_str);
```