# How to remove all spaces from a string in PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

How can I remove all spaces from a string in PHP and in Javascript? I want to remove all spaces from the left hand side, right hand side and from between each character.

For Example:

```
$myString = "  Hello   my     Dear  ";
```

I want to get this string as "HellomyDear".

Please demonstrate how I can do this in both PHP and Javascript.

Comment: @eisberg: Please click on "flag" -> "it doesn't belong here" -> "exact duplicate".

Comment: Not duplicate of that question now it has been edited (although, I would wager it is still a duplicate of another)

Answer (score 17):

**PHP**

```
$newString = str_replace(" ","",$myString);
```

**JavaScript**

```
myString.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: In Javascript it would be: `myString.replace(" ", "")`

Answer (score 7):

### Remove just spaces

**PHP:**

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $original_string);
```

[`str_replace()` man page](http://php.net/str_replace).

**Javascript:**

```
var string = original_string.replace(' ', '');
```

[`String.replace()` man page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

### Remove all whitespace

If you need to remove all whitespace from a string (including tabs etc) then you can use:

**PHP:**

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $original_string);
```

[`preg_replace()` man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

**Javascript:**

```
var string = original_string.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

use the str_replace function:

```
str_replace(' ','',$myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
$mystring = str_replace(' ', '', $mystring);
```

Javascript:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(' ', '');
```