# how to remove space in a sentence in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

can someone help me on how to remove spaces in my sql.
for exmaple
let say i type in "**I am a good boy**"... i want it to save in my mysql table column as "**iamagoodboy**" removing all spaces of anything i send.. where in this code below can i do this, thanks very much

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO messages (username,usernameto, message_content, message_time)      VALUES ("' . $username . '", "' . $messageTo . '", "' . $message . '", ' . $time . ')';

$result = mysql_query($sql, $cn) or

die(mysql_error($cn));
```

Comment: what did google have to say ?

Comment: Beware that your code offers no protection agains SQL-injection

Answer (score 3):

```
str_replace(' ', '', $message);
```

Should work fine for you in PHP. As a general rule, don't put that sort of functionality on the Database, no reason to put the load on that server - do it on the web server instead.

So your code would look like this (assuming you are taking the spaces out of `$message`):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO messages (username,usernameto, message_content, message_time)      VALUES ("' . $username . '", "' . $messageTo . '", "' . str_replace(' ', '', $message) . '", ' . $time . ')';
```

A better solution, though, might be to use `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);` which will strip all whitespace (tabs, linebreaks, etc). Depends on what exactly you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Use str_replace:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

or remove all whitespace

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

source: [How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: The preg_replace example is probably what you want as it will also replace multiple consecutive spaces, tabs and newlines

Answer (score 0):

You can replace characters using SQL ->
SELECT REPLACE(caption,'\"','\'') FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

u can try this

```
 '".str_replace(' ', '', $messageTo)."'
```

and same for other

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO messages " . 
. "(username,usernameto,message_content,message_time) " .
. "VALUES ("'.$username.'","'.$messageTo.'",REPLACE("'.$message.','' '','''')",'.$time .')';

$result = mysql_query($sql, $cn) or   die(mysql_error($cn));
```