# escape spaces in id attributes or deleting them in php section

Tags: php

i get different string (like *a, b, hospital, schools, jobs to work* etc. ) as **$divname** from my db in my PHP section. i use this values as id in mydiv elemnents.

```
<div id="'.$divname.'"></div>
```

there is no problem for $divname = *a, b, hospital or school* but when it comes to ***jobs to work*** there is a huge problem cause my id gets spaces and it returns an error to me.

```
<div id="jobs to work"></div> //as evryone state spaces in id variable is an error.
```

now my question i need use this **$divame** variables in my id attribute. how can i do this? how can i delete those spaces or any more idea for using those in id attributes are welcome.

Comment: use htmlentities maybe ? http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: or you can replace the space with underscore or something before assigning the names to the div elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a php command in another [Sof question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)  for this purpose

```
$new_divname = str_replace(' ', '', $divname);
```

it deletes all spaces.. and of course my question gets a dublicate:

Answer (score 1):

You may do two things:

1. Use a hashing function to create new id, which will be unqiue as long as your ids are unique as:

   ```
   $newdivid = md5($olddivid);
   ```
2. You may write a function to remove spaces and combine such string items

   ```
   function remove_spaces($str) {
      $str_arr = explode(' ', $str);
      $newstr = "";
      foreach($str_arr as $sitem){
          $newstr .= trim($sitem);
      }
      return $newstr;
   }
   ```

Hope this solves your problem.