# trim all whitespace around string

Tags: php, trim

So I have this output:

```
Line 1.
Line 2.
Line 3.
Line 4. Data
Line 5.
Line 6.
```

I want to have:

```
Line1. Data
```

What I do:

```
trim($dom->saveHTML(), "\n");
```

What I get (6th line removed, I want line 1, 2, 3, 5 to be removed as well):

```
Line 1.
Line 2.
Line 3.
Line 4. Data
Line 5.
```

What I get literally:

[image: What I get literally]

Comment: There's probably something in line 1, 2, 3, and 5 that isn't a `\n` character that you're trimming. Look at the data with a hex viewer.

Comment: Like what? http://scr.hu/1n9b/pv2bq

Comment: Like `\t`, a space, `\r`, `\0`, `\x0b` etc. etc. etc. etc. There's thousands of characters that look like whitespace.

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: That said, you realize that `trim($string, "\n")` **only** trims the `\n` character, right?

Comment: How do you want to show that data in hexviewer: http://scr.hu/1n9b/28e0d

Comment: @KyleHodgetts I don't want to replace, I want to `trim`

Comment: By downloading the data and using a hex viewer or using one of the thousand implementations of a hex viewer that exists in PHP or even using the lazy method that is `urlencode`. Do something.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I do know It's trimming only `n1`, as I expect only that to surround my data.

Comment: @Ultra So what makes you think there isn't a `\r` in there? or a space? or a tab? or a NULL byte? or a vertical tab?

Comment: @h2ooooooo `urlencode`: `string '%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%0D%0Adata%0D%0A%09' (length=34)`

Comment: Try removing the second parameter it will take care all of the whitespace characters.

Comment: Then you know that it's equal to `0D`, `0A`, etc., which is `\r` and `\n`. The text you pasted is equal to `\r\n\r\n\t\r\ndata\r\n\t`. Not `\n`. Use an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com).

Comment: @RahilWazir Thats correct one, post it as an answer please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string is equal to `\r\n\r\n\t\r\ndata\r\n\t` which is `CR LF CR LF TAB CR LF "data" CR LF TAB`. You're only trimming `LF` (`\n`) in your `trim()` call, which is why you don't trim `CR` (`\r`) and `TAB` (`\t`) also present in your string.

Try removing the second parameter (which specifies what characters should be trimmed), it will take care all of the whitespace characters.

As of [Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. **Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:**

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Comment: Windows and Linux return characters are not the same. On Linux it would be `/n` and on Windows `\r\n` or are that worng bells ringing?

Comment: @Ultra I guess you mean: `On Linux it would be \n`

Comment: @Ultra Different OS'es use `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n` or in rare instances `\n\r`. [Newline - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: @Ultra There is no line ending `/n` in Linux