# Strip_Tags yielding strange result and how to display HTML tags as text

Tags: html, strip-tags

Good morning!

I'm trying to scrape a CME web page to pull the table at the bottom to a two dimensional array. (http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html)

Code is below. Problem is, the var_dump says string(507) but there are only about 300 characters displayed! Three questions:

1) How do I display any hidden tags or characters?
2) Why does it say 507 chars but only about 300 chars displayed?
3) How do I remove whatever characters are hidden?

Thank you for your help!

Here is the code I used:

```
$EMiniURL = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html";
$EMiniRaw = file_get_contents($EMiniURL);
$EMiniRaw = strip_tags($EMiniRaw);
$StartChr = strpos($EMiniRaw, "About This Report") + strlen("About This Report");
$EndChr = strpos($EMiniRaw, "Total", $StartChr) - strlen("Total");
$TotalLen = $EndChr - $StartChr;
$RawStr = substr ($EMiniRaw, $StartChr, $TotalLen);
var_dump ($RawStr);
```

And here is the var_dump result:

string(532) " DEC 14 1938.50 1964.50 1935.75 1959.75 +21.75 1960.25 1,551,405 2,751,445 MAR 15 1931.00 1956.25B 1928.00A 1952.00A +21.75 1952.50 2,244 5,495 JUN 15 1920.25 1949.00B 1920.25 1945.00A +22.00 1945.50 88 350 SEP 15 1925.00 1937.75B 1925.00 1937.75B +21.75 1938.75 6 204 DEC 15 1935.75 1935.75 1935.75 1935.75 +22.00 1932.75 1 212 "

Comment: 1) There are whitespace characters, they can't be displayed 2) see 1 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: Thank you! How is it I'm not seeing almost 200 whitespace characters? I've tried copying the screen of output to Word and counting chars and blanks and still only about 300 of them. I've tried trim also. And no difference. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were newlines and tabs. Apparently PHP strip_tags does not remove everything. Used the following to finish the clean up:

```
$NewStr = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $OldStr);
```

Just saying ;)