# Deleting spaces from a string

Tags: php

I have a form where people enter their multiple codes.
Now, I would like to delete the spaces between these codes.
However, my code doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

```
$codes = $_GET['codes'];
$spaces = strpos($codes, " ");

for($spaces; $spaces=0; $spaces--){
str_replace(" ", "", $codes);
echo $codes;
}
```

EDIT: I just have tried something else but it still doesnt work at all. I mean the echo gives me the original string every single time.

```
$codes = $_GET['codes'];
$cleancodes = str_replace(" ", "", $codes);
$cleancodes = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $cleancodes));
echo "<br / >" . $cleancodes;
```

Comment: No for loop, no strpos, just `str_replace()` ... ?!

Comment: Your for loop sets $spaces to 0 so there is nothing to replace,maybe show what you have in $_GET

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: can you please show `$codes` value?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Codes contains whatever you put into form textarea.

Comment: at least provide tet case example for which you are saying that answers are not working.thank.

Comment: Lets say i type in textarea "delete the s p a c e s" and echo gives me exactly the same string

Comment: hey its working for your test cases. just check your code . you missed something.

Comment: @LetMeLearn123  can you please show us the output of `var_dump($_GET['codes']);`?

Comment: @LetMeLearn123 it's your responsibility to check answers and mark one answer which is most suitable to you. It will help future visitors to find out solution easily.Thanks.(You can up-vote others too if they are useful)

Answer (score 5):

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

Comment: it seems that your answer is much similar to Hanky.

Comment: He posted it while I was writing it, I did not copy. He posted it only 30 secs before I did

Comment: Thank you, he's 28k5 fame, i only have 105, I deserve more upvote than him xD (just kidding)

Comment: I just have edited my post, but it still doesnt seem to work at all

Answer (score 4):

```
$text=str_replace(" ","",$text);
```

But doing that for code? Bound to break (if you meant program code)!

Comment: I just have edited my post, but it still doesnt seem to work at all

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_replace()`:-

```
<?php
$_GET['codes'] = "abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz ";
$codes = $_GET['codes'];
$codes = str_replace(" ","",$codes);
echo $codes;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/395364

Comment: I just have edited my post, but it still doesnt seem to work at all

Comment: @LetMeLearn123  can you show the output of  `var_dump($_GET['codes']);`?