# How to remove white space in PHP generate css class?

Tags: php

I would like to remove white space in a php generated css code, I have different title header which would like to generate through php code.

Titles are like 1) Baby Day Care 2) Baby Night Care

My php codes are like:

```
<div class="wistia<?php echo $subject->title;?>">
```

So when I got the class, I got like `wistiaBaby Day Care` or `wistiaBaby Night Care`

But I want the class will be look like `wistiaBabyDayCare` or `wistiaBabyNightCare`
(I want space removed between text).

So how I am going to achieve that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 0):

That should to the trick:

```
<div class="wistia<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $subject->title);?>">
```

This just uses the str_replace function where you replace the first character with the 2nd character for a given string.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any whitespace simply use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (regex):

```
<div class="wistia<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $subject->title);?>">
```