# How to replace a whitespace in chosen username?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace a chosen username with blankspaces with no spaces.

```
preg_replace("[ ]", "", $username);
```

Comment: can you try `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $username);`

Comment: can you please explain what '/\s+/' menas

Comment: It's searching for whitespaces `\s+ says "match a sequence, made up of one or more space characters"`

Comment: Have a look on this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: does this link solve your problem ?

Comment: @S.I. thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @JahangirAlam thanks too, its anoother way to do what i searched for :)

Comment: @Blueblazer. Is my answer solved your request that you have opted for.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P there is a time lock to mark a question as 'worked for me'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow any of the methods provided below for the removal of the white spaces from the string.

1. For just spaces, use `str_replace`: [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

`$chosen_string = str_replace(' ', '', $chosen_string);`

2. For all whitespace, use`preg_replace`: [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

`$chosen_string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $chosen_string);`

**Cheat Sheet Reference:**

[image]

Comment: it's correct then why -ve marking? +1

Comment: Please justify why -ve marks over to this answer

Comment: Still no explanations for the `-ve` marking over to my answer :(

Comment: Maybe because it's duplicate and answer can be as comment.