# php - Remove All Strings Starting From The First Specific Character

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this kind of string:
`DURATION        : 00:23:55.060000000`

I want to convert it to this:
`00:23:55.060000000`

Please note that after `DURATION`, it has many spaces.

**EDIT:**

It seems that I made you upset, guys. :D

I did this and not working:
`preg_replace('/^Duration,\s+/', '', $result[20])`

How to do it with `php`?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Add your PHP code that you have tried so far so I can help you out better.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/cvCF6L/1

Comment: `echo end(explode(':', $string));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: Is your duration always in this format (numbers)?

Comment: edit made, adding what I did..

Comment: So, you've searched for lowercase, and your string is in uppercase... `preg_replace('/^Duration\s+: /i', '', $result[20])`

Comment: You've already have **three** solutions just in the comments. Pick whatever.

Comment: @Niitaku yes, it is.

Comment: And what's with the comma in your regex. Use @yivi's solution (which he/she maybe should add as an answer ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is messed up. You are looking for something in uppercase and your regex is in lowercase. And there is a comma laying around.

So if you rewrite that [like](https://repl.it/FUA1/2):

```
preg_replace('/^Duration\s+: /i', '', $result[20])
```

(the `i` modifier after the regular expression says its *case insenstive*)

or:

```
preg_replace('/^DURATION\s+: /', '', $result[20])
```

It'll work.

But mostly, it seems that you want to catch the timestamp, and disregard the rest. For me, the code would be much clearer if your regex reflected that.

[E.g.](https://repl.it/FUA1/2):

```
if (preg_match("|(?<timestamp>\d\d:\d\d\:\d\d\.\d{9})|", $string, $matches)) {
     echo $matches['timestamp'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
$duration = substr($duration, strpos($duration, (":")) + 2);
```

Comment: I give a solution that works, and down vote. I don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this can be useful for others who need it:

`preg_replace('/duration|^(.*?):|\s/i', '', $result[20]);`

code explanation:
first, strip the duration, and then the first colon `:` lastly all spaces.
put `i` at the end to the regex to declare that the search is incase-sensitive.

Comment: already posted it as an answer, with commentary and alternative solution. :)

Comment: are you sure it is working? it is not working on my side.
test it like this: `$var = "DURATION        : 00:23:55.060000000";` `preg_replace('/^Duration\s+: /i', '', $var);`