# working with str_replace with two combined variables

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this two variable that I combined

```
${$monthNamelower . $category[$k]}= $row['COUNT(mycategory)'];//example output decStationery
```

if my `$category[$k]` is more than two words

Example Electrical Appliance

How do I remove the space using str replace so it would be

ElectricalApplicance instead of Electrical Appliance ?

Comment: String replace usually works like that: str_replace('replace"this', 'with_this', 'in_this_string');. Optionally add .count at the end to check how many times it did the transform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **preg_replace**
Just like this

```
$category[$k] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $category[$k]);
```