# Why won't mysql default value work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been learning php and currently trying to make a
simple article/blog. I want user to enter "**Title**" and "**Body**"
of the article but **Author** is not necessary, therefore I want
Author to have a default value of "**Anonymous**". So when a user submits a post it will have an id, title, name, body. If "**name**" is
not specified it'll have the value of "**Anonymous**"

My **post** table
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7FLs.png)

**Here is my php code**

```
<?php
$errorClass = 'errorClass';

$msg = '';
$msgClass = 'alert-danger';


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // get data
    $title = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']));
    $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $post = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['post']));

    if(!empty($title) AND !empty($post)){

        // connect to the database
        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $db = "blog";


        $conn = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db);
        if($conn->connect_error){
            echo "Error:". $conn->connect_error;
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO post(title,name,post) VALUES ('$title','$name','$post')";
            if($conn->query($sql)){
                $msg = 'Success';
                $msgClass = 'alert-success';
            } else {
                echo " error" .mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }




    } else {
        $msg = 'Please fill in empty areas.';
        $msgClass = 'alert-danger';

    }

}


?>
```

**And there is the HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/lumen/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script>
        function sendTo(){
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost/blog/";
            }, 1000);
        }

        function validateInput(){
            if(document.myForm.title.value === "" && document.myForm.body.value === ""){
                document.myForm.title.style.borderColor = 'red';
                document.myForm.body.style.borderColor = 'red';
                document.myForm.title.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyBlog</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="new_post.php">Create Post</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <?php if($msg != ""):  ?>
        <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateInput()" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Create new blog post</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  class="col-lg-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="title" placeholder="Enter a title for your post..."  name="title" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAPhJREFUOBHlU70KgzAQPlMhEvoQTg6OPoOjT+JWOnRqkUKHgqWP4OQbOPokTk6OTkVULNSLVc62oJmbIdzd95NcuGjX2/3YVI/Ts+t0WLE2ut5xsQ0O+90F6UxFjAI8qNcEGONia08e6MNONYwCS7EQAizLmtGUDEzTBNd1fxsYhjEBnHPQNG3KKTYV34F8ec/zwHEciOMYyrIE3/ehKAqIoggo9inGXKmFXwbyBkmSQJqmUNe15IRhCG3byphitm1/eUzDM4qR0TTNjEixGdAnSi3keS5vSk2UDKqqgizLqB4YzvassiKhGtZ/jDMtLOnHz7TE+yf8BaDZXA509yeBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name..."  name="name" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAPhJREFUOBHlU70KgzAQPlMhEvoQTg6OPoOjT+JWOnRqkUKHgqWP4OQbOPokTk6OTkVULNSLVc62oJmbIdzd95NcuGjX2/3YVI/Ts+t0WLE2ut5xsQ0O+90F6UxFjAI8qNcEGONia08e6MNONYwCS7EQAizLmtGUDEzTBNd1fxsYhjEBnHPQNG3KKTYV34F8ec/zwHEciOMYyrIE3/ehKAqIoggo9inGXKmFXwbyBkmSQJqmUNe15IRhCG3byphitm1/eUzDM4qR0TTNjEixGdAnSi3keS5vSk2UDKqqgizLqB4YzvassiKhGtZ/jDMtLOnHz7TE+yf8BaDZXA509yeBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Textarea</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="post" id="body"></textarea>
                        <span class="help-block">Write your feelings...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendTo()">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just check if the name field is empty and assign it a value before inserting it into mysql?

```
if (empty($name)){
$name = 'Anonymous';
}
```

Comment: Ok this is awkward. This one worked but why did not that DEFAULT option in sql did not work?

Comment: What is inserted into your database without this code? is it null, or a space?
I personally try to avoid using default values in db when coding except for auto increment columns

Comment: just empty space

Comment: In that case, try to strip the variable of all whitespace before inserting it into mysql and see how it goes.
$name = str_replace(' ',''', $name);
You can also try the regex version found here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Use Condition before inserting your data,

```
if(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']))){
  $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
}else{
  $name = 'Anonymous';
}
```

Hope this helps :)