# how to remove the white space using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to remove the white space in Actual invoice amount the screen shot and code that are shown at the below cases.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Actual Invoice Amount</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
             <input type="text" name="payment_act_invamt" id="act_invamt" class="form-control act_invamt"  placeholder="Actual Invoice Amount"   required>  
             </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What about using input `type="number"`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the JavaScript `trim()` method. this method will remove white spaces from both side of string

```js
function InvoiceAmount(){
    var input_value = document.getElementById("act_invamt").value;
    alert(input_value + "\n" + input_value.trim())
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Actual Invoice Amount</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="payment_act_invamt" id="act_invamt" class="form-control act_invamt"  placeholder="Actual Invoice Amount"   required >

<button onclick="InvoiceAmount()">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

Here I have show difference of using `trim` method and without using `trim` method

Comment: Yes, this. And since your question is tagged with PHP, maybe [also do this server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var formvalue = $('input[name="somename"]').val();

formvalue = formvalue.trim();
    
$('input[name="somename"]').val(formvalue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <input type="text" name="somename" value="    9000">
  
</form>
```

Comment: we can use only form field names not the database value..9000 is the database value

Comment: See Updated Answer

Comment: 9000 is the value only for particular invoice no..if the invoice no changes amount also change..and also dont want alert just it can visible only in text box.

Comment: alert is only for demonstration. you can use modify it as per your requirment.

Comment: ok ok..but it alert also it doesnt show the values...it shows the blank value

Answer (score 0):

// Try this . i hope it's useful ..

```
var act_invamt = document.getElementById("act_invamt").value
var str = act_invamt.replace(/\s/g, '');

alert(str); die;
```

Comment: Please check my Update Answer .

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery `trim()` which remove both left and right space, first show space with input value then when click remove space then remove space

```js
 function removeSpace() {
    var inputvalue = $('input[name="payment_act_invamt"]').val();

    inputvalue = inputvalue.trim();

    $('input[name="payment_act_invamt"]').val(inputvalue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="payment_act_invamt" value="    9000">
    <input type="button" onclick="removeSpace()" value="Remove Space" />

</form>
```

so you can use this code which remove space from input filed

```js
  var inputvalue = $('input[name="payment_act_invamt"]').val();

        inputvalue = inputvalue.trim();

        $('input[name="payment_act_invamt"]').val(inputvalue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="payment_act_invamt" value="    9000">

</form>
```