# Remove spaces from a text file

Tags: php

How do I remove spaces from a text file? I tried the code below but I could not:

**The file**

```
10400000         2090183800001990000000000000000000001234204321000000000EMPRESA                       C ECON FEDERAL                          20601201405551100162204000000                    RETORNO-PRODUCAO                  000            
10400011T0100030 20090183800001990000000000000000000001234204321000000000EMPRESA                                                                                                       00001622060120140000000000
```

**How the file has to stay:**

> 02RETORNO0000000000000000011119999990000000000000000000000000000000000000000104000000000000000201016000000000

**The code**

```
 $arquivo = fopen($_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"], "r");
$arquivo = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $arquivo);

while (!feof($arquivo)) {
  $linhas = fread($ler,999999);
  $banco = substr($linhas,0,3);
  $lote = substr($linhas,4,7);
  $registro = substr($linhas,8,8);
}
echo "Banco: " .$banco. "<br>";
echo "Lote: " .$lote. "<br>";
echo "Registro: " .$registro. "<br>";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: Your code is not changing the file at all, it only reads from it. If you want something to be removed from the file, then you should at least write to it.

Comment: Right. I changed my post.

Comment: I tried using the code: `$arquivo = preg_replace ('/\s+/', '', $arquivo);` Before the while () but when I run, it keeps reading and crashes the browser.

Comment: The change you've made is nonsensical. `preg_replace` works on strings, but `$arquivo` is a file handle. And you still aren't writing anything anywhere.

Comment: Read the file, store the contents in a variable, remove the spaces using `preg_replace` or `str_replace` and rewrite the file?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `file_get_contents` ?

try this..

```
$ar = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
$arquivo = file_get_contents($ar);
$arquivo = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $arquivo);
```