# What is the difference between space and whitespace in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the difference between **space** and **whitespace** in PHP?

I saw on different places that to **strip out all the spaces** use `str_replace()` and use `preg_replace()` for **whitespace**.

Here is a reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109339/4003463

Comment: What does that mean? Why should there be any difference?

Comment: Whitespace is a programming language or just a space .. I guess in your question you want to know that, but there is not any difference

Comment: @Ende Thankyou,  Space is a normal space between words, while whitespace is any kind of space in text: regular space, new line, tab, etc

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes. This is a good question.

Comment: @Sipo indeed. I hope it's because the downvoters consider it fundamental.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the added context to your question, a space is ascii 32 (that is, what you get when you press the spacebar).

A whitespace is any character that renders as a space, that is:

- A space character
- A tab character
- A carriage return character
- A new line character
- A vertical tab character
- A form feed character

Comment: "Space" can be just `\u0020` as you say, but it can also be non-breaking space (`\u00A0`) or full-width space (`\u3000`), or one of other unicode codepoints that look like (and are used as) space. I agree that in context of `str_replace`, they probably just meant the "normal" space (`\u0020`), given that that function can't replace several different things in one run (unlike `preg_replace`).

Comment: Is there any replacement for "white space", such as "any space"?

Comment: @DawnSong what do you mean by "any space"? How would it be different from the concept of whitespace?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca There is "white space", and no "black space". There might be some more inclusive word.

Comment: Don't charge words with meanings they do not have. "White space" is because we usually write on white paper and there is a literal "white space" where there are no words. It's not charged, it doesn't have a positive meaning as opposed to "black space", which is not even a thing. Let's not make this very important fight against racism ridiculous to the point where people just mock it.