# problem with brackets in video name ffmpeg php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm using ffmpeg to put a watermark on video but when my video has a name that contains brackets it's not doing anything

```
$a = "10 (1).mp4";
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $a -i $logo -filter_complex \"[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7,scale=iw*0.4:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)/(main_h-overlay_h)\" watermarked1.mp4";
exec($cmd);
```

when I change the name to 10 its working

Comment: Where's "tha name"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I think it's the space issue. Change your **file name**  from `10 (1).mp4` to `10(1).mp4` and see if it works. I suspect the space makes it assume as a command or a flag.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm using xampp and I have no debugger

Comment: @vivek_23 you are right thanks man . what should I do with the space?

Comment: @HadiAhmadi if the file is on our file system, then it's done. Are you receiving this name programmatically from somewhere?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes it's from somewhere and a lot of these files that makes it impossible to edit them manually

Comment: What do you mean by "have no debugger"? `var_dump` is alright to check the command itself, and then you can run it manually to see what happens. Additionally, `exec` returns whatever the execution returns, and you haven't checked whether this return value contains some information

Comment: @HadiAhmadi In that case, you could loop through each file and use [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to rename file names by removing spaces between them.

Comment: @NicoHaase vardump is giving me the file does not exist and no more

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks a lot. let me know if you found a way to do it in code

Comment: @HadiAhmadi Of course, you could. How are you receiving the file names though(via code) ?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes via code. I'm reading every file names in a folder and making a loop by foreach

Comment: @HadiAhmadi This link should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php/2109339

Comment: From the duplicate I think you just need to add quotes round the file name `"$ffmpeg -i \"$a\" -i $logo`

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks alot

Comment: @NigelRen its not working

Comment: You may want to try `exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd))`, or `exec(escapeshellarg($cmd))` see if this helps.

Comment: @NigelRen \"$a\" this one worked after a few changes in code thanks a lot. and also sorry if you felt insulted I'm new in PHP and kinda slow. thanks a lot