# PHP: Ignoring whitespaces and casing in form validation

Tags: php, mysql, validation, whitespace, casing

I'm creating an educational platform in which courses (course codes) are created. I want to be able to prevent a new course code from being inserted ignoring the case being used or use of whitespace. e.g if "PHY 101" already exists and one types in "phy101". It should reject the new entry.

```
$new_course = $_POST['new_course'];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course = '$new_course'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $num_row=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if($num_row === 1){
          echo "<script>
          alert('Course code already exists.');
          window.location = 'create_newcourse.php';
          </script>";                                
        }
```

Comment: Sorry abt that. Kindly answer if you know it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I strip all spaces out of a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-do-i-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Not really @mitkosoft. Some entries in the database already have spacing: such as "PHY 101". I want to be able to prevent something like "phy101" from being inserted.

Comment: then you need to apply this logic (lowercase, no whitespaces) both over `course` column and `$_POST['new_course']`

Comment: When you insert data doesn't matter if you insert Upper or Lower alwys will reject if exist

Comment: Good comment, only that we can't predict the casing users will use. Can there simply be a code to examing the characters alone and ignore the casing or spaces used?

Comment: Thanks @SimoneRossaini

Comment: @Godlovesme Work?

Comment: I'd go a bit further and store a second field in the database (lower, no whitespace) strictly for searching this condition on. Doing all the conversions in the WHERE clause can be painful on large tables of data.

Comment: Please do not use `or die(mysqli_error($conn))`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15318368/1839439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have records on your `courses` table, then you need to equalize both strings (`course` column and `$_POST['new_course']`) upfront:

```
$new_course = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '',$_POST['new_course']));
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(`cource`, ' ', '')) = '$new_course'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

If you don't need formatted `$new_course` value further, you can perform both modifications only on SQL level, like:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(`cource`, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE('$new_course', ' ', ''))") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Good point @PaulSpiegel, not really needed, thank you!. The answer is updated.

Comment: @mitkosoft are you sure:   lowercase(str_replace(' ', '',$_POST['new_course'])); really works?

Comment: @Godlovesme, of course not! :) My mistake, it must be `strtolower`, updated.