# How to replace white-space with <br>?

Tags: php, html

I have a text where I want to bypass using the css property white-space:

```
white-space: pre-line
```

How can I replace white-spaces in a text with a break (`<br>`) in PHP so that I have the same output like using `white-space: pre-line`?

Example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1 Referer: http://192.168.2.154/ Cookie: PHPSESSID=s0p0vc93nf630ornkvdprgc5ko;security=impossible Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Host: 192.168.2.154 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36 Connection: Keep-alive
```

How can I format this code without css (white-space) that I have it like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://192.168.2.154/
Cookie: PHPSESSID=s0p0vc93nf630ornkvdprgc5ko;security=impossible
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: 192.168.2.154
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
Connection: Keep-alive
```

Comment: Where is your php attempt that is not working?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Sorry... What I've tried: str_replace('  ', '<br>', $text);

Comment: CSS's `white-space` attribute is telling the browser how the content should be rendered in the browser. PHP doesn't render anything since it's server side, so PHP can't replace CSS attributes like this.

Comment: Is there any possibility to render it first and then to replace the white-spaces and get the new code with the replaced white-spaces?

Comment: You really need to give us a proper example if you want us to be able to give you proper and relevant suggestions. Your question is a too unclear atm. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have add an example, I hope it's now better to understand

Comment: The example (all on one line), is that what it looks like in the browser? Does it look correct if you check the source (right click on the page and click on "view source"?) If it's just in the browser it looks like one line, it could be that it has line breaks (which browsers don't render). In that case, try: `$text = nl2br($text);`. If you really has it as only a one-liner, then it's a bit trickier.

Comment: So far I see a sample bit of code that is CSS, and an HTTP request and response. Where is the PHP? Why doesn't your `str_replace` work. Have you tried [`preg_replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109339/231316)?

Answer (score 1):

My strong guess is that the PHP generated response is already on multiple lines, but the browser is rendering it in "HTML mode" (because of the default `text/html` content type), thus line-breaks are transformed into single spaces.

Depending on your use-case, you can either use function `nl2br()` or set the `text/plain` content type for the response:

```php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```