# Simplest way to get a complete list of all the UTF-8 whitespace characters in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, whitespace, space

In PHP, what's the most elegant way to get the complete list (array of strings) of all the Unicode [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(computer_science)), encoded in utf8?

I need that to generate test data.

Comment: If you want that to replace into a string, take a look into `\p{Z}` within regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This email](http://www.bogofilter.org/pipermail/bogofilter/2003-March/001889.html) (archived [here](https://gist.github.com/Dethnull/9613129)) contains a list of all Unicode whitespace characters encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, and HTML.

In the archived link look for the 'utf8_whitespace_table' function.

```
static $whitespace = array(
    "SPACE" => "\x20",
    "NO-BREAK SPACE" => "\xc2\xa0",
    "OGHAM SPACE MARK" => "\xe1\x9a\x80",
    "EN QUAD" => "\xe2\x80\x80",
    "EM QUAD" => "\xe2\x80\x81",
    "EN SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x82",
    "EM SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x83",
    "THREE-PER-EM SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x84",
    "FOUR-PER-EM SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x85",
    "SIX-PER-EM SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x86",
    "FIGURE SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x87",
    "PUNCTUATION SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x88",
    "THIN SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x89",
    "HAIR SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x8a",
    "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\x8b",
    "NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE" => "\xe2\x80\xaf",
    "MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE" => "\xe2\x81\x9f",
    "IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE" => "\xe3\x80\x80",
);
```

Comment: oh! Its missing the two I am looking for. x2028, line separator and x2029 paragraph boundary

Comment: Please upload the message somewhere else. This link doesn't work

Comment: Broken link. That's the reason you should **always** copy the info from the link, making the answer self-contained and not vulnerable to broken links.

Comment: With PHP 7 you can now write Unicode *code points* directly. Eg `"\u{00A0}"` instead of UTF-8 `"\xc2\xa0"` directly.

Answer (score 15):

Years later, this question still has top results on Google when looking for unicode whitespace characters.  devio's answer is great, but incomplete. As of this writing (October 2017) Wikipedia has a list of whitespace characters here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

This list has specifies 25 code points, whereas the currently accepted answer lists 18.  Including the seven other code points, the list is:

```
U+0009  character tabulation
U+000A  line feed
U+000B  line tabulation
U+000C  form feed
U+000D  carriage return
U+0020  space
U+0085  next line
U+00A0  no-break space
U+1680  ogham space mark
U+180E  mongolian vowel separator
U+2000  en quad
U+2001  em quad
U+2002  en space
U+2003  em space
U+2004  three-per-em space
U+2005  four-per-em space
U+2006  six-per-em space
U+2007  figure space
U+2008  punctuation space
U+2009  thin space
U+200A  hair space
U+200B  zero width space
U+200C  zero width non-joiner
U+200D  zero width joiner
U+2028  line separator
U+2029  paragraph separator
U+202F  narrow no-break space
U+205F  medium mathematical space
U+2060  word joiner
U+3000  ideographic space
U+FEFF  zero width non-breaking space
```

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Spaces_in_Unicode

Unfortunately, it doesn't give UTF-8, but it does have the character in the web page, so you could cut and paste into your editor (if it saves in UTF-8).  Alternatively, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/180E/index.htm gives UTF-8 (replace "180E" with the hex UTF-16 value you are looking up).

This also gives a couple extra characters that @devio's excellent answer misses.

Answer (score 1):

```
0x9 b'\t'
0xa b'\n'
0xb b'\x0b'
0xc b'\x0c'
0xd b'\r'
0x20 b' '
0x85 b'\xc2\x85'
0xa0 b'\xc2\xa0'
0x1680 b'\xe1\x9a\x80'
0x180e b'\xe1\xa0\x8e'
0x2000 b'\xe2\x80\x80'
0x2001 b'\xe2\x80\x81'
0x2002 b'\xe2\x80\x82'
0x2003 b'\xe2\x80\x83'
0x2004 b'\xe2\x80\x84'
0x2005 b'\xe2\x80\x85'
0x2006 b'\xe2\x80\x86'
0x2007 b'\xe2\x80\x87'
0x2008 b'\xe2\x80\x88'
0x2009 b'\xe2\x80\x89'
0x200a b'\xe2\x80\x8a'
0x200b b'\xe2\x80\x8b'
0x200c b'\xe2\x80\x8c'
0x200d b'\xe2\x80\x8d'
0x2028 b'\xe2\x80\xa8'
0x2029 b'\xe2\x80\xa9'
0x202f b'\xe2\x80\xaf'
0x205f b'\xe2\x81\x9f'
0x2060 b'\xe2\x81\xa0'
0x3000 b'\xe3\x80\x80'
0xfeff b'\xef\xbb\xbf'
```