# Can't get str_replace() to strip out spaces in a PHP string

Tags: php, string, str-replace

Hi, I am getting a PHP string which I need to strip the spaces out of. I have used the following code but when I echo `$classname` it just displays the string still with the spaces in it.

```
   <?php
     $fieldname = the_sub_field('venue_title');
     $classname = str_replace(' ', '', $fieldname);
     echo $classname;
   ?>
```

Comment: Use an hex editor to view the bytes, if the spaces aren't `20` in HEX then it's not a "normal" space. You may use a simple function in PHP to convert to HEX.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To strip whitespaces inside a variable in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279774/to-strip-whitespaces-inside-a-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 35):

Try to add **u**-parameter for regex-pattern, because a string can have UTF-8 encoding:

```
$classname  =  preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $fieldname);
```

Comment: Same here. String was retrived from Wordpress meta field. Was saved in admin panel, after "copy-paste" from old site, with different encoding...

Comment: you are the real mvp

Comment: That did the trick

Answer (score 16):

If you know the white space is **only due to spaces**, you can use:

```
$classname = str_replace(' ','',$fieldname );
```

But if it **could be due to space**, you can use:

```
$classname = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$fieldname )
```

Comment: Try substituting the `\s+` for `\h+` for horizontal whitespace, this will retain line breaks, if needed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem might be the character not being a space, but another whitespace character.

Try

```
$classname = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $fieldname);
```

Answer (score 3):

use trim like this

```
TRIM($fieldname);
```

EDIT:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fieldname);
```

Comment: `trim()` will only remove whitespace from the start and end of the string

Comment: 'trim()' only trims at the beginning or the end of a string. In Paul's example, whitespace characters might be within the string.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the space is not really a space, but other form of whitesspace.

You might want to try:

```
$classname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fieldname);
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php).

Comment: try substituting `\h+` for horizontal whitespace, this will retain line breaks, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the field that it was pulling, not the rest of the php. 'the_sub_field('venue_title')' pulls a field from the wordpress plugin 'Advanced Custom Fields' but this function is intended to display the data rather than just retrieve it. Instead i used 'get_sub_field('venue_title')' and it worked. cheers for the help

Comment: This is the correct answer to this threat and needs to be marked so

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $fieldname = "I  am  21  Years  Old";
  $classname = str_replace(' ', '', $fieldname);
  echo $classname;
?>
```

This runs perfectly.
Check value return by this function: `the_sub_field('venue_title')`;

Comment: I think the issue is that the string is not getting treated as a string. it needs a " on either side. how would you do this in php? eg $fieldname = "'" . the_sub_field('venue_title') . "'";

Comment: use "
". the_sub_field('venue_title').""
or maybe
""+the_sub_field('venue_title')+""