# Having trouble with using str_replace() in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, str-replace

This is my code:

```
<?php
$date_db = "2017-10-12 12:00:00";

setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");

$date_db = strtotime($date_db);

$date_db = strftime("%e. %B %Y, %A, %k:%M Uhr", $date_db);

$date_db = str_replace(":00","",$date_db);

echo $date_db;
?>
```

The output is: `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 12 Uhr`

This is all right so far. But sometimes there's no time, only a date, like this: `$date_db = "2017-10-12 00:00:00";`.

This will output: `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 0 Uhr`.

In a case like this, I want to have removed the trailing `, 0 Uhr`.

I think it should work by using this line of code below the other `str_replace` code line: `$date_db = str_replace(", 0 Uhr","",$date_db);`.

Whole code:

```
<?php
$date_db = "2017-10-12 00:00:00";

setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");

$date_db = strtotime($date_db);

$date_db = strftime("%e. %B %Y, %A, %k:%M Uhr", $date_db);

$date_db = str_replace(":00","",$date_db);

$date_db = str_replace(", 0 Uhr","",$date_db);

echo $date_db;
?>
```

This should output `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag`, but output is `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 0 Uhr`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date_db = "2017-10-12 10:00:00";
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");
$date_db = strtotime($date_db);
$date_db = strftime("%e. %B %Y, %A, %k:%M Uhr", $date_db);
$date_db = str_replace(":00","",$date_db);

//check if string contains O Uhr then only trim
if(preg_match("/ 0 Uhr/", $date_db)){
    $date_db = str_replace("0 Uhr","",$date_db);
    $date_db = rtrim($date_db, ' ,');
}
echo $date_db;
```

Comment: Works. But when using `$date_db = "2017-10-12 10:00:00";` output should be `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 10 Uhr` but it is `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 1`. Why that?

Comment: yes , i missed it. You'll have to check if string contains "0 Uhr" then only to the last two steps.

Comment: Hey @Jagrati, that works, thank you very much. But, why didn't my solution work? This isn't logical for me. Can you explain that?

Comment: check this out  it might answer to why your solution did not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563421/cant-get-str-replace-to-strip-out-spaces-in-a-php-string

Answer (score 2):

```
//(rtrim) Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string


<!---language:lang-php-->
<?php
$date_db = "2017-10-12 00:00:00";

setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");

$date_db = strtotime($date_db);

$date_db = strftime("%e. %B %Y, %A, %k:%M Uhr", $date_db);

$date_db = str_replace(":00","",$date_db);

$date_db = rtrim($date_db ,", 0 Uhr");//(rtrim) Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string

echo $date_db;
?>
```

Comment: When using `$date_db = "2017-10-12 12:00:00";` I'm getting `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 12` instead of `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 12 Uhr`. Why that?

Comment: But you wanted  "12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 12 Uhr  this one ". not this 12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 12

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean. Using this code `$date_db = "2017-10-12 12:00:00";` I want to get: `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 12 Uhr`. But with your code I'm getting only `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 12` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 0 Uhr';
$string = str_replace(", 0 Uhr", "", $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The second code works as it is. But when using `$string = "2017-10-12 00:00:00";
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");
$string = strtotime($string);
$string = strftime("%e. %B %Y, %A, %k:%M Uhr", $string);
$string = str_replace(":00","",$string);
` instead of `$string = '12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 0 Uhr';`, I'm still getting `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 0 Uhr`.

Comment: The first code also works as it is. But when using `$string = '12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 14 Uhr';` instead of `$string = '12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 0 Uhr';`, output is: `12. Oktober 2017, Donnerstag, 14`.