# str_replace vs explode in removing spaces in the middle of a string

Tags: php

Was wondering why str_replace doesn't work in my set of code, yet exploding it works.

```
$plate = "AAA 1234";
$plateNum = str_replace(' ', '', $plate);

$plateNum = explode(' ', $plateNum);

$updatedPlateNum = '';
foreach ($plateNum as $string) {
    $updatedPlateNum .= $string;
}
```

For testing purposes, "AAA 1234", the space should be omitted

edit: added $plate

Comment: They both seems to work fine by me, [demo](https://3v4l.org/p0OG0)

Comment: [seems fine for me](https://phpfiddle.tk/e3a2b1d9)? Also optimised your explode - no need for a foreach

Comment: Are there any other ALT-codes for spaces? The data was coming off of MySQL data and it might be the one that's causing the issue

Comment: I will work just echo $plateNum = str_replace(' ', '', $plate); to check.

Comment: Yes, there are [other white-space characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode). Also see [Can't get str_replace() to strip out spaces in a PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563421/cant-get-str-replace-to-strip-out-spaces-in-a-php-string) and [How can strip whitespaces in PHP's variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279774/how-can-strip-whitespaces-in-phps-variable).

Comment: use [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove extra whitespace^

Comment: @treyBake Only "from the beginning and end of a string".

Comment: @showdev good point.. although.. if the whitespace is in the middle of the text then there needs to be something set up insert-side to ensure that doesn't happen IMO, you shouldn't have to remove whitespaces from called data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get str_replace() to strip out spaces in a PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563421/cant-get-str-replace-to-strip-out-spaces-in-a-php-string).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$plate = "AAA 1234";
$string = preg_replace('/s+/', '', $plate);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a viable answer:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $plate);
```

PS: I'm not literate at regex expressions which is why I was avoiding it and was using explode and str_replace.