# Escape Spaces in this script?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to create this config file to make an executable and it works fine when the file name doesn't have any spaces but when a file have spaces it doesn't work.

the file name is inside the $readyFile variable.

What can i do to fix this ?

```
$content = ";!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title=\"Auto-Extract\"
ExecuteFile=\"Runner.exe\"
ExecuteParameters=\"--exe 2999.exe --file $readyFile\"
;!@InstallEnd@!";
$fp = fopen("config.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to double-escape a set of quotes around it; `\\\"`

Comment: Mind showing an example? \\\".$readyFile.\\\" Like that ?

Comment: If you're trying to strip the white space in the `$readyFile` variable, this may help: [To strip whitespaces inside a variable in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1279798/2774955)

Comment: @Exoon; yeah, but without the dots (you're using in-string substitution; no need to concat)

Comment: @Dave, Worked a treat. Want to add it as an answers so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can strip using this regex.

```
$content=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double-escaped quotes (`\\\"`):

```
$content = ";!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title=\"Auto-Extract\"
ExecuteFile=\"Runner.exe\"
ExecuteParameters=\"--exe 2999.exe --file \\\"$readyFile\\\"\"
;!@InstallEnd@!";
```

When PHP parses the string, it becomes `="--exe 2999.exe --file \"your file here\""`, so your inner quotes are still escaped for the call-within-a-call.