# How to remove spaces in a string using preg_replace

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

I am to remove the spaces between the initials and keep the space between initial and any word.

I would like to get this result.
**A.J.P. Jane B.V.**

Instead I am getting this result
**A.J. P. Jane B. V.**

```
$string = "A.J. P. Jane B. V.";

$string =  preg_replace('/\.\s\[A-z]{1}\./', '.', $string);

echo $string;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To strip whitespaces inside a variable in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279774/to-strip-whitespaces-inside-a-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this rule `\.\s([A-Z]{1})\.` or  `\.\s([A-Z])\.` without explicit limit
to match `[dot][space][letter][dot]` and
replace with `.$1.`, `[dot][letter][dot]`

```
$string =  preg_replace('#\.\s([A-Z]{1})\.#', '.$1.', $string);

echo $string;
```

Will output

```
A.J.P. Jane B.V.
```

Comment: Hi thanks. There is just one issue. There's a space between the . P.

Comment: The output I get is like I mentioned in the answer, make sure the code is the same

Comment: sorry you are correct, I was trying $string = "A. J. P. Jane B. V."; So I have another aspect to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: this is not the result he wanted!!

Comment: That removed all space. It should only remove some. the result should be A.J.P. Jane B.V.

Comment: see Alex Andreis answer