# I want to remove all white spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is something like the example below,

```
assd *AA*the fox saw the outcome     *EAA*saassdsd
```

I want to remove the whitespace between *AA* and *EAA* using regex. Using the code below I can highlight everything between *AA* and *EAA* but I only want all the spaces to be highlighted. I believe this (.*) is grouping all the characters. Can someone point me in the right direction thanks?

```
 \*AA\*(.*)\*EAA\*
```

Comment: **\s** is a space in regex

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1279798

Comment: sorry should of said **white** space, which in regex lingo means "Matches any space, tab or newline character."

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you trying to remove the spaces btw `outcome and *EAA*` or all the whitespaces in the string? if the later, then I suggest you use the `preg_replace` function.

Comment: I am trying to remove the whitespace between *AA* and *EAA*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears that you want to remove all spaces from given string.

```
function sanitize($string)
{
    $re = "/^(.*?AA)(.*)(EAA.*)$/i";

    preg_match_all($re, $string, $matches);

    if($matches) {
        $p1 = $matches[1][0];
        $p2 = $matches[2][0];
        $p3 = $matches[3][0];

        $p2 = preg_replace("/\\s+/", "", $p2);

        $result = $p1.$p2.$p3;
        return $result;
    }
    return $string;
}

$str = "assd *AA*the fox saw the outcome     *EAA*saassdsd ";
print(sanitize($str))
```

This will render:

```
assd *AA*thefoxsawtheoutcome*EAA*saassdsd
```

Comment: This is really close except it removes the whitespace outside *AA* and *EAA*

Comment: I just tried  \*AA\*(\s+)\*EAA\* and that did not highlight the whitespace

Comment: So what is your expectation? Remove spaces inside AA

Comment: It never occurred to me to create three groups