# SMARTY : Remove whitespace at the beginning or end of my string in Smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty, whitespace, trim

Here's my string seperated by commas (,)
`$myStr = "One, Two,Three, Four , Five ,Six "`

I am able successfully explode it `{assign var="options" value=","|explode:$myStr}`

But I also would like to remove whitespace at the beginning or end from each string when outputting it. In other words: I am looking for a **SMARTY** function equivalent to PHP's built-in `trim($mystr)` function. PHP trim will remove the start and end white-spaces if it present, otherwise return the actual string.

```
{section name=myname loop=$options}
   {$options[myname]}
{/section}
```

The code above would output:

> ```
> One
> Two
> Three
> [whitespace]Four[whitespace]
> [whitespace]Five[whitespace]
> Six[whitespace]
> ```

How can I trim whitespaces?

Comment: Duplicate please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279774/to-strip-whitespaces-inside-a-variable-in-php

Comment: No. Its not duplicate. Both are different questions. My concern is about to remove the white spaces at **start** and **end** positions only. Question which you mentioned is about removing all spaces from a string.

Comment: I am looking for a **SMARTY** equilent of PHP trim($mystr) function. PHP trim will remove the start and end white-spaces if its present, otherwise return the actual string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [{strip}{/strip}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.strip.tpl) in smarty.
Whitespaces will be removed between theese tags.

`{$var|substr:0:-1}` would remove last character in your case the whitespace. `{$var|substr:1}` would remove the first character from string.

> all php-functions can be used as modifiers implicitly (more below) and
>   modifiers can be combined

from [docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl) `{$var|trim}` in smarty is equal to `trim($var)` in php.

There is another way. Using `{php}{/php}` tags in in smarty to able to use php built-in `trim()` function, but that makes no sense to me. Why would you even want to put smarty variable back to php if it was included by php? Nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it will remove all the spaces with in the string. I want to remove the whitespaces onloy from both ends of a string.

Comment: Thank you again, But it will remove the first and last characters from the string, if white-spaces are not presented at ends. I am looking for a php quilent of trim($mystr). PHP trim will remove the start and end whitespaces if its present, otherwise return the actual string.

Comment: works for me. just tested. `$smarty->assign('text', ' empty ');` and then in smarty `{$text|trim}` removed the whitespaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109172/discussion-between-ksno-and-eldho-newage).

Answer (score 0):

If the white space is just whitespace as in space characters, you can use the function `trim()` ([Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)) to strip it. Replace `$options[myname]` with `trim($options[myname])`.

If it's the string "[whitespace]", you can use `preg_replace()` ([Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)) like: `preg_replace("/[whitespace]/","",$options[myname])`

Comment: I know in php to do this. But my question is about SMARTY .